# Riddle - What does it mean?

Tags: riddle, knowledge, poetry

What am I? `03/04/19 13:36 UTC`

*This is very abundant*
*The most that you'll see*
*And its group and number*
*Is what you will need*

*Now somewhat repetetive*
*For you who are us*
*You may now start the task*
*From now, not before*

*You use this to move*
*Or choose where to go*
*How much am I spotty?*
*You need to know*

*Some think this will curse you*
*But they've got it wrong*
*Not quite a domino*
*How many of me?*

*If your friend in Jakarta*
*Wants you to get on the horn*
*Then to be direct*
*Just remember me*

*Take dozen of the best*
*Not more, not less*
*Now look to the last*
*And there this will rest*

Hint #1: `03/04/19 18:48 UTC`

> *Though once I was rejected*
>  *I am now well known*
>  *For I am a part of*
>  *All that are equal and right*

Hint #2: `04/04/19 13:30 UTC`

> *Work out what each is*
>  *For it's a joint effort*
>  *Then take them conjointly*
>  *And then you will know what I am*

Hint #3: `04/04/19 22:33 UTC`

> *If you value your pieces*
>  *Then put them together*
>  *You will soon find*
>  *You're close to the answer*

Hint #4: `06/04/19 18:57 UTC`

> *Though I'm very well known*
>  *No one can tell you what I am*
>  *I'm quite small, but I never end*
>  *And you can work on me forever*

Hint #5: `08/04/19 15:20 UTC`

> *When solving the first*
>  *Look in the Earth's crust*
>  *That's part of the answer*
>  *Now find the rest*

Do you like it? This is my first riddle, so sorry if it's not too good. Not sure what tags I should include to avoid giving extra hints. Note: the timestamps are just that, timestamps. All you need is in the stanzas.

Comment: Very nice riddle! Some tag suggestions: If the answer is a single word, include the "word" tag. The "poetry" tag would almost certainly be appropriate, since your riddle appears to be in poem form. If you have any wordplay involved, there's a "wordplay" tag. _If any unusual knowledge is required, throw in a "knowledge" tag - the absence or presence of this tag is typically very important._

Comment: @Brandon_J Does unusual word/phrase choices go under `wordplay`?

Comment: Wordplay is essentially a fancy way of saying "puns." I guess no one wanted to make a "pun" tag :)

Comment: @Brandon_J I'll leave it for now then.

Comment: @ArtemisFowl the number pi?  it was once rejected by the senate. There is a mall in Indonesia which abbreviates to pi mall.

Comment: @Mel ***Close!***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the answer is

> $\sqrt{2} \approx 1.41421356237\ldots$

This is very abundant
The most that you'll see
And its group and number
Is what you will need

> I think this refers to silicon - the second most abundant element in the Earth's crust (but the most abundant that can be *seen*) with atomic number **14**.

Now somewhat repetitive
For you who are us
You may now start the task
From now, not before

> Repetition of **14** from the first part

You use this to move
Or choose where to go
How much am I spotty?
You need to know

> This refers to a die. Add up the spots on a die and you get **21**

Some think this will curse you
But they've got it wrong
Not quite a domino
How many of me?

> Hexomino (hex + domino) - of which there are **35**

If your friend in Jakarta
Wants you to get on the horn
Then to be direct
Just remember me

> As others have said the dialling code for Indonesia is **62**

Take dozen of the best
Not more, not less
Now look to the last
And there this will rest

> The 12th *prime* number is **37**

Put it all together

> **14 - 14 - 21 - 35 - 62 - 37** $\rightarrow$ 1.41421356237 $\approx \sqrt{2}$

Hint #1

> Irrational numbers were not accepted as being true numbers by the Ancient Greeks but nowadays, we would include them. $\sqrt{2}$ appears as the measure of the hypotenuse of an isoceles triangle with other side lengths equal to 1.

Comment: Correct! You've missed something in stanza 2 though.

Answer (score 3):

are you

> international phone number such as the one for Indonesia ( Jakarta)  +62 21 xxx xxxx

This is very abundant

The most that you'll see

And its group and number

Is what you will need

> It is abundant as almost everyone has a phone number. A phone number has "section" / "groups" of numbers. It is necessary it today's world

Now somewhat repetitive

For you who are us

You may now start the task

From now, not before

> us as in United States. You have to enter coutnry code while calling internationally. The reference to starting the task can be attributed to the following: 
>
>  When calling international numbers there is a wait between entering the country code and then entering area code followed by the number. Sometimes this is guided by a voice over "please enter your xx now"

You use this to move

Or choose where to go

How much am I spotty?

You need to know

> you can transfer phone numbers (i.e. move ) , you can also choose your own phone number . Spotty as in spotty phone signal. Need to know the coverage.

Some think this will curse you

But they've got it wrong

Not quite a domino

How many of me?

> There was/is a trend of [cell phone signal causing cancer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_phone_radiation_and_health) ( i.e. curse you) But there is no evidence to this.

If your friend in Jakarta

Wants you to get on the horn

Then to be direct

Just remember me

> Jakarta is the capital of Indonesia. "to get on the horn" means to speak to someone on the phone.  There is international direct dialing.

Take dozen of the best

Not more, not less

Now look to the last

And there this will rest

> Indonesian phone numbers, when called internationally, are dialed using 12 characters. example: +62 21 xxx xxxx

Comment: Nope! But you are on the right lines for the fifth stanza.

Comment: @ArtemisFowl my other guess was a clock/watch , but it seemed too simple

Comment: Check out my latest clue.

Comment: @ArtemisFowl latest clue still makes me think its an analog clock with the hour and minute hand pointing. ( Work out what each is) need both to tell time(For it's a joint effort,Then take them conjointly) you then will know what time it is.(And then you will know what I am ) . The first hint also fits ; change in  Swiss clocks were once rejected

Comment: Um, nice theory...

Comment: There's another one up there now, or at least a clarification of the second. (This comment **does not** include any hidden meaning)

Comment: @ArtemisFowl dice?

Comment: Nope. There's another clue up there.

Answer (score 1):

> This is very abundant
>   The most that you'll see
>   And its group and
>   number Is what you will need

Are you

> hydrogen? oxygen? or H20- group and number derived from periodic table of elements?

Comment: Very close, pay attention to line 2. This is only a partial answer, you'll need the entire riddle.

Answer (score 0):

are you

> carbon 
>  Carbon is the 15th most abundant element. Used as fuel in its appropriate form ( use it to move) . There is the [curse of the diamond](https://www.livescience.com/45239-hope-diamond-curse.html) 
>  carbon's atomic mass is 12 ( dozen of the best) . Carbon has pi bonds (cue pi mall in Indonesia) . Also Carbon 12 is most common.

Comment: This is close to the answer for the first stanza, you'll need the entire poem to get your solution. There's another hint up there.

Answer (score 0):

I’m feeling like we are looking for

> A particular hydrocarbon or petroleum product

And I think it’s

> **Diesel**

This is very abundant

The most that you'll see

And its group and number

Is what you will need

> Carbon is the most abundant element that is not a gas *that you can see*

Now somewhat repetetive

For you who are us

You may now start the task

From now, not before

You use this to move

Or choose where to go

How much am I spotty?

You need to know

> Reference to a type of fuel (gasoline/diesel/fossil) and *how much am I spotted* could refer to [tlc](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thin-layer_chromatography)

Some think this will curse you

But they've got it wrong

Not quite a domino

How many of me?

> Could refer to the [curse of oil](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_curse) and maybe a chain of dominos similar to a hydrocarbon chain?

If your friend in Jakarta

Wants you to get on the horn

Then to be direct

Just remember me

> Country code is 62 and there is a 62 grade diesel

Take dozen of the best

Not more, not less

Now look to the last

And there this will rest

> This feels like it’s referring to oil refining, taking the first 12 petroleum products and the answer is the remaining one?

Comment: Your answer to the first stanza is close, but you'll need the entire poem to find the answer. There's another hint up there.